# Why does a triac trigger with gate current in either direction?

Tags: power-electronics, triac, semiconductors, gate-driving, thyristor

I've been coming up to speed on thyristors, and triacs in particular. I've found detailed material on them a little hard to find, in particular on the device physics. Horowitz & Hill is silent on them, Sedra & Smith as well, not even a mention.

I suppose I get a vague idea that thyristors belong a bit to a past era, but they're still a key component in solid state relays (SSR) for example, so I thought I'd be able to dig up more.

Anyway, one of the questions that's still open for me is why a triac triggers with gate current in either direction (in/out). That seems a bit odd so definitely aroused my curiosity.

[image]

Does anyone understand how that bit works?

Comment: The [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC) has a decent start on this, but the explanation of Q4 is a bit lacking. Try to avoid Q4- either drive with the same polarity on the gate as MT2, or always drive it with negative current .

Comment: Oooh, not sure how I missed that resource on search, it looks like just the ticket, thanks Spehro! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the triac as two thyristors connected back to back with their gate connections commoned.

[image]

On each half cycle the appropriate 'thyristor' is fired. The downside is that the triggering voltages are not symmetric. To improve this a DIAC is used at the gate input.